# Use Spring Cloud Function and Spring Cloud Stream together?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

Has anyone tried using both Spring Cloud Function and Spring Cloud Stream together? Is there any reason this shouldn't be done? We currently use Spring Cloud Function but there are certain cases where we need to have synchronous Kafka publishing and it seems as if the only way to do that is with Spring Cloud Stream.

Thanks, Anne

Comment: Could you elaborate what the issues that you are running into? Spring Cloud Stream uses Spring Cloud Function internally.

Comment: Spring Cloud Function doesn't support synchronous publishing and that's what we're currently using. Spring Cloud Stream does but the switch would be a lot of work, so I was wondering if anyone had ever used them both together and if so were there any issues.

Comment: I was looking for something similar - wherein I wanted to use spring cloud functions exposed as rest endpoint as well as can be applied as kafka channels - for ex - a "function" takes input from POST rest endpoint and publish to a topic - rather then creating a separate endpoint and then poll from it with EmitterProcessor to a supplier.