# Is it possible for Spring Cloud Stream to use both old @EnableBinding-@StreamListener and new functional style in one project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Below is the code with both types of kafka consumers which I try to use .

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(MixApplication.IncomingBinding.class)
@Slf4j
public class MixApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final ConfigurableApplicationContext application
                = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MixApplication.class).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET).run(args);

    }

    @StreamListener(IncomingBinding.INPUT)
    public void listen(Object obj){
        log.info("hello1");
    }

    @Bean("output2")
    public Consumer<Object> output2() {
        return obj -> {
            log.info("hello2");
        };
    }

    public interface IncomingBinding {
        String INPUT = "output1";

        @Input(INPUT)
        SubscribableChannel input();
    }
}
```

with configuration

```
spring:
  application:
    name: MixApplication
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: output2
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        output2-in-0:
          destination: test2
          group: "test"
          consumer:
            concurrency: 10
            max-attempts: 3
        output1:
          destination: test1
          group: "test"
          consumer:
            concurrency: 10
            max-attempts: 3
```

But only consumer with @StreamListener annotation is working.

When I remove @StreamListener realization then "output2" consumer works. Is it possible to make them both work together?
Also I have seen similar item, but it was without answer.
[Use Spring Cloud Function and Spring Cloud Stream together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017126/use-spring-cloud-function-and-spring-cloud-stream-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you could only use one or the other, but since version 4.0 annotation-based programming model is completely removed which means you can *only* use function-based.

What is it that you want to do that you can not do with function-based model?

Comment: I try to add new consumer to project which is not migrated to functional style. And I do not want to write new code with deprecated elements. So I want to make new consumer and than migrate old. But after your answer I think need to change order of this actions. Thanks for answer.